# Change the background color of a row based on field value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form. I need to be able to change the background of a row in a table based on a the value of a field in another row.

Example:

Row A. Field #1 value=YES

Based on the YES vale

Row B. Background changes to yellow.

Comment: Can you provide actual mark up?

Comment: Add `onchange` eventlistener to `Field#1`, in the handler function, check if the value of `Field#1` is `YES` and then set background style of `Row2` to yellow.

Comment: Try something, then we may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about doing what you want. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vramdhanie/SKUG2/) for a simple example. Type Yes in the textbox to see the highlight change. With some more info in your question I can modify the example to make it more useful.

Say you had the following HTML:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="field1"/></td>
        <td>Something else</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowb">
        <td>Some value</td>
        <td>Some other value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And the following jQuery JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#field1").change(function(){
          $(".rowb").addClass($("#field1").val() == "Yes"?"highlight":"lowlight");
      });
 });
```

And the following CSS:

```
   .highlight{
    background-color:yellow;
}

.lowlight{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first give filed 1 and row 2 an id by using the id attribute

is the value already set to true when the html loaded ??

if yes add onLoad="changeBG" to the table
if no add onChange="changeBG" on the feild1
and then add this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function  changeBG () {
    if(document.getElementById("feild1").getAttribute(value) == true)
       document.getElementById("rowB").setAttribute(background-color,yellow) ;
       }
</script>
```